# How to hide the Catalog Advanced Search in magento version 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, advanced-search

I am working on a Magento e-commerce site.
I need to disable the Catalog Advanced Search.
I checked with source code available in the stackexchange but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the link to advanced search edit `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/catalogsearch.xml`.
If the file does not exist in your theme, copy it from `base/default`. Then remove this from the file:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch">
    <label>Advanced Search</label>
    <url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl" />
    <title>Advanced Search</title>
</action>
```

But this will still leave your controller active, and anyone with a link can access it.
To restrict this, create an observer for the events `controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_advanced_index` and `controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_advanced_result` with this code:

```
public function restrictAccess($observer)
{
    $url = Mage::getUrl('no-route');
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
}
```

This will redirect the users to a 404 page when trying to access the advanced search form or result page.

Comment: Yep , I tried the same thing but the functionality is still working

Comment: make sure your observer is called.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy below file in your theme directory
   **app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalogsearch.xml**
2. search the layout **catalogsearch_advanced_index** & Just comment out the code inside that tag to hide the advance search content.